# Inplace Forward Fill on a multi-level column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, hierarchical, fillna

I have the following dataframe:

```
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux'],
 ['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two']]
tuples = list(zip(*arrays))
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples, names=['first', 'second'])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3, 8), index=['A', 'B', 'C'], columns=index)
df.loc["B", (slice(None), 'two')]=np.nan
```

Now, I want to forward fill inplace the data for columns "baz" and "foo" (so not for columns "bar" and "qux"). I tried:

```
 df[["baz", "foo"]].ffill(inplace=True)
```

but the resulting dataframe did not forward fill any of the values. 
How can I create a dataframe with forward filled data for those two columns only?

Comment: Works for me on v0.20. What version are you using?

Comment: Same here , 0.20 pandas works well

Comment: I use version 0.20.3. The function does not give an error, but if I print the df, the NaN data is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem comes due to the `inplace=True` setting. Try accessing the slice with `df.loc` and then assigning the `ffill`ed dataframe slice back:

```
df.loc[:, ["baz", "foo"]] = df[["baz", "foo"]].ffill()
```

Output:

```
first        baz                 foo          
second       one       two       one       two
A       0.465254  0.629161 -0.176656 -1.263927
B       2.051213  0.629161  1.539584 -1.263927
C      -0.463592 -0.240445 -0.014090  0.170188
```

---

Alternatively, you could use `df.fillna(method='ffill')`:

```
df.loc[:, ["baz", "foo"]] = df[["baz", "foo"]].fillna(method='ffill')
```

Comment: Thanks, that works indeed. However, it is extremely slow on my original dataframe (which has 30*3000 columns and 163000 rows). While the forward fill calculation (df[ffill_list].ffill(limit=None) takes around 3 seconds), the allocation in the df takes 5 minutes (using df.loc[:,ffill_list] = df[ffill_list].ffill(limit=None)).

Comment: @user6538642 Afraid loc based setting is the _only_ way to update slices.

Comment: @user6538642 Sorry, ignore the `inplace=True`, it just doesn't work for slices, because inplace=True also creates copies, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above did not work for me, but this did:

```
df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, ['baz', 'foo']] = df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice[:, 'baz', foo']].fillna(method='ffill')
```

IIUC, the [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) method has been depreciated.